# multipath on iscsi target is it posible?

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, iscsi, multipath

Is it possible to configure multipath on target iscsi SAN? I configured multipath on vmware iscsi initiator and it's work but bouth flows goes on the one SAN storage port with the IP but is it posible to use one ip on different SAN ports becose target is equal IP even if it's bond port (san is oceanstor 5300 v3)?

Comment: It would be appreciated if you took the time to formulate a good question, rather than spewing a stream of consciousness.

Comment: Check if Round Robin (active-active MPIO) is enabled in vCenter https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/5.5/com.vmware.vsphere.storage.doc/GUID-AE95818C-0782-429B-9526-DF12673A63C7.html

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure about your multi-path on exactly this SAN box model. So, I will elaborate a bit on multi-path in general.

The idea of multi-path (for convenience I'll call it MPIO in the following text) is to create 2 paths from A to B, it can be either storage and compute resourses or VMs and datastore. Thus if one of connections/paths will go down (in case node or NIC died) MPIO feature will provide you with access to you data due to 2 connections ( 1 connection in scenario what I described will be "dead").

If you are looking to learn more about MPIO, or looking to create HA/redundant storage I would recommend to check https://www.starwindsoftware.com/technical_papers/StarWind_MPIO.pdf AFAIK they are using MPIO on iSCSI to provide 2 (or more) paths.